# Powershell Script Error-Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property': Cannot index into a null array

Tags: powershell, null, powershell-4.0

I have run a Powershell script found within this article: [How to detect applications using "hardcoded" DC name or IP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2014/07/13/how-to-detect-applications-using-hardcoded-dc-name-or-ip/#comment-975).

[image: The code is as follows:]

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName dc01.contoso.com -MaxEvents 1000 -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Directory Service" ; ID=1139 } | ForEach-Object ` 
{
 $_info = @{
 "Operation" = [string] $_.Properties.Value[0]
 "User" = [string] $_.Properties.Value[2]
 "IP:Port" = [string] $_.Properties.Value[3]
 }
 New-Object psobject -Property $_info
 }
```

The error I receive is:

```
New-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\scripts\HideDC.ps1:9 char:37
+        New-Object psobject -Property <<<<  $_info     
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Object], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\scripts\HideDC.ps1:5 char:55
+            "Operation" = [string] $_.Properties.Value[ <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Post your code in the question. Don't use pictures for your code.

Comment: Debug the code, set a breakpoint in PowerShell ISE inside the loop and check the variable values.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**:

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName dc01.contoso.com -MaxEvents 1000 -FilterHashtable @{
  LogName="Directory Service" ; ID=1139 } |
    ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        "Operation" = try { [string] $_.Properties.Value[0] } catch {}
        "User" =      try { [string] $_.Properties.Value[2] } catch {}
        "IP:Port" =   try { [string] $_.Properties.Value[3] } catch {}
      }
    }
```

---

- The `Cannot index into a null array` error message is telling you that `$_.Properties.Value` is `$null` rather than an array, so an attempt to access an element of this non-array *fails*.<sup>[1]</sup>

The implication is that at least some of the event-log records do not have embedded data values.

- (The `New-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'` is merely a follow-on error that complains about the `-Property` argument being `$null`, because the initial error caused `$_info` to be `$null`.)

  - The simplest solution is to use an embedded `try { ... } catch {}` handler enclosing the `$_.Properties.Value[<n>]` references, which quietly ignores the case when `$_.Properties.Value` is `$null` and causes the overall subexpression to return `$null`.
  - Also note how you can cast the hashtable literal (`@{ ... }`) directly to type accelerator `[pscustomobject]` in order to convert it to a custom object.

---

<sup>[1] Note that since PSv3, trying to index into a value that is non-`$null`  but is also *not an array* doesn't *fail*, but quietly returns `$null`; e.g.: `$v=20; $v[1] # -> $null`.

Indexing into a *string* value is a special case, however: it returns the *character* at the specified position: `$v='hi'; $v[1] # -> 'i'`</sup>